# Rebase workflow with pull requests on bitbucket cloud

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have created two branches on bitbucket cloud and created two pull requests each of the two branches. Pull requests merging strategy is set to "merge commit". The commit tree looks like the following after merging the pull requests:

[image]

These are the merging strategies:
[image]
How is it possible to avoid this szenario on bitbucket cloud? What is the point in rebasing, if the branch can look this or is this the exception?

Comment: In your case, I would pick fast-forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BitBucket has its [own merge strategies for pull requests](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/pull-request-merge-strategies-844499235.html) including:

> ### Rebase, fast-forward (`rebase` + `merge --ff-only`):
>
> Commits from the source branch onto the target branch, creating a new non-merge commit for each incoming commit.
> Fast-forwards the target branch with the resulting commits. The PR branch is not modified by this operation.

And:

> ### Fast-forward only (`--ff-only`):
>
> If the source branch is out of date with the target branch, reject the merge request. Otherwise, update the target branch to the latest commit on the source branch.

Either one would avoid a merge commit and produced a linear history.

The second one supposes the PR branch was rebased locally at the developer workstation, then `push --force`: the merge becomes trivial.

---

The [OP David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10738638/david) asks [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554842/rebase-workflow-with-pull-requests-on-bitbucket-cloud/61596666#comment108959688_61596666):

> So I need to rebase every second pull request locally, if there are two pull requests created at the same time?

The fact two PR are created "at the same time" is not relevant in that process.

One of them will be merged (without issue, since it is the first to be merged)

The second won't be merged (rejected, because not a fast-froward merge)

The developer won't have any other choice but to:

- pull master to update it with the mast changed (here the first merged PR)
- rebase the second PR locally on top of master (resolving conflict locally, making sure it still works)
- force pushing
- merging the second PR through the Web GUI (the merge is a fast-forward one, it will be accepted)

That process involving a local reconciliation is the usual best practice.

Comment: there is only one fast forward strategy in the cloud

Comment: @David OK: the second one it is then: fast-forward.

Comment: you would need to rebase the second pull request then, before you merge it, right? that is, what i was going to avoid

Comment: @David Rebase locally then force push. What should that be avoided? The diea is to resolve any conflict locally and check the second PR still works when applied on top of the first (which was first merged)

Comment: But what if the pull request was not applied on the first, because they were created at the same time?

Comment: @David That is why you rebase locally: once the first is merged, you update master (which will include the first), rebase the second, force push, and merge.

Comment: So i need to rebase every second pull request locally, if there are two pull requests created at the same time?

Comment: @David The fact that those PR have been created at the same time is of no importance: Once one of the two is merged, *then* (and only then) you rebase the second one on top of master (since master now includes the merged PR)

Comment: If bitbucket would have "Rebase, fast-forward" in the cloud, i would not need to rebase locally in that case, correct?

Comment: @David Yes, but the best practice remains a local rebase, because you can test locally if the second rebase PR is still working, before force pushing it.

Comment: High price to pay for rebasing

Comment: @David Not really: the work is done locally, validated by the developer of the PR (leaning by the person who knows best how to test said PR). Once force pushed, the merge is trivial: less work to do on the remote side.

Comment: but if i have two PRs, i need to advice one developer to rebase a second time, correct?

Comment: The idea is that the second PR is rebased once the first has been merged to master. Since the merge strategy is fast forward, the second PR *cannot* be merged: that will be your "notification" for the developer to rebase their PR.

Comment: @David I have sumarized the main points of our discussion in the (edited) answer. If I have missed something, let me know.